# Javascript calling API array handling with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling a BUS ETA api which it will return a json with ETA and route information. Example as below. I manage to get the first array to show in HTML but without success for the second `[1]` and third`[2]`. I manage to see all three ETA with console.log but won't show in HTML.

Any idea?

UPDATE : Created a jsFiddle example.

https://jsfiddle.net/21tk38b9/

**BUS ETA API SAMPLE DATA**

```
{
  "type": "ETA",
  "version": "1.0",
  "generated_timestamp": "2021-06-29T16:02:53+08:00",
  "data": [
    {
      "co": "KMB",
      "route": "978",
      "dir": "I",
      "service_type": 1,
      "seq": 7,
      "dest_tc": "粉嶺(華明)",
      "dest_sc": "粉岭(华明)",
      "dest_en": "FANLING (WAH MING)",
      "eta_seq": 1,
      "eta": "2021-06-29T16:11:24+08:00",
      "rmk_tc": "",
      "rmk_sc": "",
      "rmk_en": "",
      "data_timestamp": "2021-06-29T16:02:41+08:00"
    },
    {
      "co": "KMB",
      "route": "978",
      "dir": "I",
      "service_type": 1,
      "seq": 7,
      "dest_tc": "粉嶺(華明)",
      "dest_sc": "粉岭(华明)",
      "dest_en": "FANLING (WAH MING)",
      "eta_seq": 2,
      "eta": "2021-06-29T16:28:15+08:00",
      "rmk_tc": "原定班次",
      "rmk_sc": "原定班次",
      "rmk_en": "Scheduled Bus",
      "data_timestamp": "2021-06-29T16:02:41+08:00"
    },
    {
      "co": "KMB",
      "route": "978",
      "dir": "I",
      "service_type": 1,
      "seq": 7,
      "dest_tc": "粉嶺(華明)",
      "dest_sc": "粉岭(华明)",
      "dest_en": "FANLING (WAH MING)",
      "eta_seq": 3,
      "eta": "2021-06-29T16:43:15+08:00",
      "rmk_tc": "原定班次",
      "rmk_sc": "原定班次",
      "rmk_en": "Scheduled Bus",
      "data_timestamp": "2021-06-29T16:02:41+08:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Mining Status</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/src/js/Untitled-4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/15.css">
<style type="text/css">
.fullscreen {
               position: fixed; 
    overflow-y:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

</style>


</head>

<div id="wrap">


<body>
<div style="    
font-size: 100px;
text-align: center;">
<div id="rmk"></div>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Route</th>
      <th scope="col">ETA</th>
      <th scope="col">Remark</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td><div id="route"></div></td>
      <td><div id="but"></div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td></td>
      <td><div id="but"></div>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




</body>
    </div>

</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function repeat57() {
$(function() {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://data.etabus.gov.hk/v1/transport/kmb/eta/83B717529F9794BC/978/1",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
        console.log(typeof data); // -- Object
        var json = data;
                for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
                    var str = json.data[i].eta
                if (str !== null ) {
                    str = str.split("T").pop();
                    str2 = str.split("+",1).pop();
                    str3 = str2.replace(/:/g,'');
                    d = new Date();
                    datetext = d.toTimeString();
                    datetext = datetext.split(' ')[0];
                    datetext = datetext.replace(/:/g,'');
                    console.log(datetext)
                var eta = str3 - datetext;

                console.log(eta)

                 var eta2 = "[ " + eta.toString().slice(0, -2) +" mins,]";
                } else {
                    var remark = json.data[i].rmk_tc
                    eta2 = remark;
                }
                console.log(typeof str)
        $('#but').html(eta2);
                $('#rmk').html(remark);
            }
}
});
});
setTimeout(repeat57, 19000);
}
repeat57();


function repeat58() {
    $(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://data.etabus.gov.hk/v1/transport/kmb/eta/83B717529F9794BC/978/1",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
                    var json = data;
                    console.log(typeof .json)
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
                        var str = JSON.parse(json.data[i].route)
                    if (str !== null ) {
                    
                    } else {
                        var remark = json.data[i].rmk_tc
                        str = remark;
                    }
                    console.log(typeof str)
                    $('#route').html(str);
                }
    }
    });
    });
    setTimeout(repeat58, 19000);
    }
    repeat58();
```

Comment: Can you maybe provider a working example here? Or on jsFiddle? Which we can run. Would be easier in order to help you.

Comment: Sure. https://jsfiddle.net/21tk38b9/ Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to be dynamic or are there always only 3 entries?
If there are three entries you could do:

HTML Code:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="rmk"></div>

  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Route</th>
        <th scope="col">ETA</th>
        <th scope="col">Remark</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>
          <div class="route"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="but"></div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>
          <div class="route"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="but"></div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
         <td>
          <div class="route"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="but"></div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function repeat57() {
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://data.etabus.gov.hk/v1/transport/kmb/eta/83B717529F9794BC/978/1",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); // -- Object
        var json = data;
        const buts = $('.but');
        for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
          var str = json.data[i].eta
          if (str !== null) {
            str = str.split("T").pop();
            str2 = str.split("+", 1).pop();
            str3 = str2.replace(/:/g, '');
            d = new Date();
            datetext = d.toTimeString();
            datetext = datetext.split(' ')[0];
            datetext = datetext.replace(/:/g, '');
            console.log(datetext)
            var eta = str3 - datetext;
            var eta2 = eta.toString().slice(0, -2) + " mins";
          } else {
            var remark = json.data[i].rmk_tc
            eta2 = remark;
          }
          $(buts[i]).html(eta2);
        }
      }
    });
  });
  setTimeout(repeat57, 19000);
}
repeat57();


function repeat58() {
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://data.etabus.gov.hk/v1/transport/kmb/eta/83B717529F9794BC/978/1",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        var json = data;
        console.log(json)
        const routeElements = $('.route');
        for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
          var str = JSON.parse(json.data[i].route)
          if (str !== null) {

          } else {
            var remark = json.data[i].rmk_tc
            str = remark;
          }
          $(routeElements[i]).html(str);
        }
      }
    });
  });
  setTimeout(repeat58, 19000);
}
repeat58();
```

Make sure to change the ids to classes (but, route, etc) and add it to all the rows where it is needed.

And when iterating through the result you pick the correct element via the index.

See the updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sgjx05qf/

This would be a solution if you always know the count of the result.

Comment: You could make it more dynamic and refactor the code a bit :)